# Finding a vector $\mathbf{u}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $L = \mathbf{u}+W$.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $L$ be the line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the equation $y = x+1$. Find a vector $\mathbf{u}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $L = \mathbf{u}+W$.
What exactly is it asking? Help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a line parallel to it passing through $(0,0)$ namely $\{x=y\}$. So take $W=\{(x,y): y=x\}$ and $u=(0,1)$ (or any other point on the given line).

Comment: Thank you very much!  Let $L$ be the set of solutions $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the equation $x-5y-2z = 1$. Find a vector $\mathbf{u}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $L = \mathbf{u}+W$.