# Find a vector $\mathbf{u}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $L = \mathbf{u}+W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $L$ be the set of solutions $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the equation $x-5y-2z = 1$. Find a vector $\mathbf{u}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $L = \mathbf{u}+W$.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311198/finding-a-vector-mathbfu-in-mathbbr2-and-a-subspace-w-of-mathbbr) is where I asked a similar question in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that was simple enough but what about in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Thank you!

Comment: It is always a special solution plus a subspace of the homogeneous system. So pick any special solution and then solve $x-5y-2z=0$.

Comment: There is no significant difference between solving a problem like this in $\Bbb R^2$ and in $\Bbb R^3$. There is an extra coordinate and an extra variable, but that doesn't really change anything. The answer just looks a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf u$ be a solution of that equation ($(1,2,-5)$, for instance) and let$$W=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid x-5y-2z=0\}.$$Then $L=\mathbf u+W$.

Comment: Gotcha thank you!